# Why does RestTemplate returns ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> instead of real list of model type?

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

It is a Springboot project. The code snip is as below. At line 59, the desired retrun type for `restTemplate.getForEntity` is `List<Template>`. While debugging, I find that the actual return type is an ArrayList contains many LinkedHashMap.

While LinkedHashMap is not sub class of Template. I don't know why the expect result type and the actual result type match.

Could anyone tell why it doesn't return `ArrayList<Template>`, instead of `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>`? Thanks.

[image]

Template is an model defined in our project.

```
public class Template {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String content;

    xxx getters and setters
}
```

And it is a controller where the resttemplate is invoked.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getTemplatesByGroup", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public EUDataGrid<Template> getTemplatesByGroup(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "-1") Integer groupId) {
        EUDataGrid<Template> grid = new EUDataGrid<>();

            xxxx
            List<Template> list = restTemplate.getForEntity(urlFullTemplates, ArrayList.class).getBody();
            xxxx

        return grid;
    }
```

Json result format as below

```
[
    {
        "id": 1788,
        "name": "xxxx",
        "content": "xxxxx."
    },
    {
        "id": 1787,
        "name": "xxxxx",
        "content": "xxxx"
    }
]
```

Edit:

I googled a lot for this issue again. It is a common problem. There are similar scenarios some guys also encountered. I add the link in the foot of this post.

It seems that this is a bug of RestTemplate to handle generic properly. And there are ways to resolve this.

Here I want to know, **why it doesn't throw exception when restTemplate returns `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>` and assign it to `List<Template>`**? They are differnt types. This is some kind of like assgin an int to a string.

I guess there is some magic with generic type. Could someone tell more about this? Thanks.

[Unable to get a generic ResponseEntity<T> where T is a generic class "SomeClass<SomeGenericType>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819734/unable-to-get-a-generic-responseentityt-where-t-is-a-generic-class-someclass/13820584#13820584)

[Using Spring RestTemplate in generic method with generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987295/using-spring-resttemplate-in-generic-method-with-generic-parameter)

[RestTemplate: how to get generic List response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834296/resttemplate-how-to-get-generic-list-response)

Comment: Can you please correct this bit *Could anyone tell why it doesn't return ArrayList, instead of ArrayList* and also add your code? Also what type is `Template`?

Comment: Hi Madhu, can you see a screen shot in this post? It seems that i.stack.imgur.coml is blocked in China, and I am not sure whether I upload it successfully. That screen shot contains code and debug runtime detail.

Comment: I am able to see the screenshot, but adding code around that would be easier for the community to help you. Also, what type is `Template`, as in where is it imported from?

Comment: can do please do this GET call through client and show us the JSON response @RobinSun

Comment: In the links you added showed how to do with `exchange` method, so either you can follow that or use `Template[].class` @RobinSun

Comment: Hi @Deadpool, my question here is not just how to convert it. I want to know why it doesn't throw any exception. They are differnt types.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem in JSON response you are getting `List<Template>` or Array of `Template`, but in the `responseType` you just specified `ArrayList` where jackson doesn't know which type of `ArrayList` it is

[limitation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list) See the limitation

```
 getForEntity(URI url, Class<T> responseType)
```

> This sends a request to the specified URI using the GET verb and converts the response body into the requested Java type. This works great for most classes, but it has a limitation: we cannot get lists of objects.

One way is simple just specify Array type

```
Template[] list = restTemplate.getForEntity(urlFullTemplates, Template[].class).getBody();
```

Or use the [exchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-) method

Comment: Hi,  Template[] works. Thanks. Do you know why it doesn't throw exception at code line 59? I declare it as List<Template>, but JVM assgin List<LinkedHashMap> to it with no exception. What a magic.

Comment: Json is key value pair, if object mapper don't know in which type it need to deserialize it will choose Map as default @2 so it will not throw any exception

Comment: As I understand, if I declare a var with type A, only the instance of class A or instance of sub class A could be assgined to it. So can I think that ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> is sub class of List<Template> ?

Comment: This is`ArrayList.class` by default represented like this `List<Object>` and the above JSON 
    `{
        "id": 1788,
        "name": "xxxx",
        "content": "xxxxx."
    },` this in `Map` format, that is the reason it gets deserialized into `List<HashMap>` @RobinSun